# "Sudo apt update" error repository not signed

Tags: apt, 18.04

I have encountered this error today that when I run `sudo apt update` in 18.04, It gives this output:

```
Get:1 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [253 B]
Err:1 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                       
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [261 B]                       
Err:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                               
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [263 B]                     
Err:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                             
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                
Ign:5 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                        
Hit:6 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 18.04, can you tell how exactly I can change the server to main one.

Comment: In KDE Plasma, there is no such thing as `Software & Updates`.  It comes with a discover application where changing the server is not an option.